# Unable to connect to rdp on linux from windows Almalinux 8.6

Tags: windows, rdp, alma-linux

I am trying to connect from RDP(mstsc.exe) from windows machine to my linux machine. I have installed xrdp and can see that the port 3389 is being listened on. But the RDP fails due to(Communication administratively filtered). I reviewed the firewall settings on IP tables and everything looks fine. I am able to ssh just fine, it's just the rdp that's failing.Is there a setting on firewall or router setting that i need to change to allow this traffic ?
192.168.1.50 is my Linux machine and 192.168.1.2 is my windows machine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ICMP Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)

means port is filtered (blocked) on
192.168.1.50.

> Is there a setting on firewall or router setting that i need to change to allow this traffic ?

Oga.

> I reviewed the firewall settings on IP tables and everything looks fine.

"Fine" is a when everthing works. So its not fine. Add

```
sudo iptables -nvL
sudo nft -n list ruleset
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
```

output to be sure.

Its likely firewalld uses nftables instead of iptables.

```
cat /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf | grep FirewallBackend
```

Allow tcp 3389 on 192.168.1.50

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent
```

Comment: I should've been clear when i said iptables looked fine. i added the port using command

sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

Added the output here
[link](https://pastebin.com/H9m39JvE)

Comment: Aaaa are you kidding? You dont understand how it works? **input dport**, **output sport** you need both if your rules not stateful

Comment: I don't have enough shame not to admit that I didn't pay attention to the syntax when I copied. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is it works now?